# Objects are not valid as a React child (found: [object Promise]) in react render

Tags: javascript, reactjs, es6-promise

I have a Class-based React component. This is a child component and the state comes from another parent component. This is the JSX and it is inside a map function. Inside the map function, there is a big JSX code but I am putting only the relevant part.

```
{platformsList.map((item, index) => (
{item.platform_id ? (
<div>
   {this.getSelectedProfiles(item.platform_id)}
</div>)) : ''}
```

The corresponding function is written above the render method. The response is an Object here:

```
getSelectedProfiles = async(id) => {
    const token = Cookie.get('user-token');
    const headers = {
      'Content-Type': 'application/json',
      authorization: token,
    };
    // Axios request  
    let response = await axios.get(`http://localhost:9999/profiles/${id}`, { headers: headers });
    console.log(response);
    return 'kkk';
  }
```

The error message it is showing is:
Error: Objects are not valid as a React child (found: [object Promise]). If you meant to render a collection of children, use an array instead.

Since, this is a child component, I don't want to store in the state of React. I want to execute this component. Is there any way to do it without storing it in the state. I am new to React and don't know where I am doing wrong.

Comment: Your question will be much clearer if you provide a [mcve]. I have in mind a component class with the minimal code that gives the context of what you are trying to do.

Comment: What does the rest of your component look like? How are you managing state?

Comment: I have edited and updated the question. I think it will give you a better idea.

Answer (score 1):

An async function returns a promise, it does not immediately execute and return a value (in this case `'kkk'`). There does not seem to be any reason `getSelectedProfiles` is async either, so just remove that and make it synchronous.

```
  getSelectedProfiles = (id) => {
    return 'kkk';
  }
```

Comment: "There does not seem to be any reason getSelectedProfiles is async eithe" Unless the `return 'kkk';` is just intended to show simple logic that will run, but hides complexity that must be async and has nothing to do with the question.

Comment: Well yes. If they need to do an asynchronous action inside React that is a different question however.

Comment: I read the question as "how do I get the results of an async function to render them?"

Answer (score 0):

You need to `await` on the result from the function call:

```
render () {
  const getSelectedProfiles = async(id) => {
    return 'kkk';
  }
  const selectedProfiles = await getSelectedProfiles(item.platform_id);

  return {item.platform_id ? (
    <div>
     {selectedProfiles}
    </div>) : ''}
```

However, this has the drawback that `async` is blocking. If the async operation in `getSelectedProfiles()` is long running (such as a network request), your render will hang. In that case, you must set the state of your component instead.